# Reliability of returned value of Future method cancel(false)

Tags: java, future

Suppose I schedule a task with a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and get a Future back.

I later decide I want to cancel that Future, and rely on the returned value of the **cancel** to trigger some cleanup operation. I don't want the task to be interrupted if it's already running (so I pass **false** as argument).

Is the return of the cancel reliable? That is, **is it impossible** that, if cancel returned "true", the task is actually being run?

Looking at the code in the OpenJDK 8 it looks like there could be a race condition, whereby the "cancel" sets the state of the task to CANCELLED and returns true, but the runner can already have passed the "check" to start execution.

As far as I can see, the computation will be performed but the result not set (which is good). However, in my case, the "computation" has side effects so I want to know if I cancelled it for real or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc of `cancel(boolean)` states

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. **This attempt will fail** if
>   the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could
>   not be cancelled for some other reason.
>
> **If successful**, and this task
>   has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If
>   the task has already started, then the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter
>   determines whether the thread executing this task should be
>   interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.

Emphasis mine. The call will return `true` under all conditions which aren't failures. It is therefore possible that the method returns `true` and your task is running.

Comment: Indeed. I should have read better the doc before diving into the code. Can you advise on a class with the semantics I need? Otherwise, I'll roll my own. Thanks.

Comment: @FabioT. I don't know of a different API for this, but you may want to rethink the side-effects if possible.